# Angular 12 moved component's module import doesn't work

Tags: angular, import, module

I need to restructure some of my components and I moved my user component's folder into the home component's folder. Visual Studio Code asked if I wanted to update the imports and I clicked yes.

However, the user page HTML gives the '' is not a known element error.
I tried to import the modules I use again in the user module, but it still doesn't work.

Also I tried if I import it in the home module, but that didn't work either.

#### File *user.page.html*

```
<h1>Profile page</h1>
<app-login></app-login>
```

#### File *user.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { UserPage } from './user.page';
import { UserPageRoutingModule } from './user.routing.module';
import { LoginModule } from 'src/app/core/components/login/login.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    UserPageRoutingModule,
    LoginModule,
  ],
  declarations: [UserPage],
})

export class UserPageModule {}
```

#### login component

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
})

export class LoginComponent {
  ...
}
```

#### Login.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule,
  ],
  exports: [LoginComponent],
})
export class LoginModule {}
```

Comment: please add the content of your LoginModule

Comment: i would try to restart the IDE

Comment: Yes I meant Visual studio code, and i added the content of the LoginModule

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that yes I tried to shut down the console and then start again, and also closed visual studio and reopened it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to found the solution, in the home router I had to import the user module, even if I don't use it anywhere in the router.